# callback outside for loop, closure inside loop, and ''synchronous'' events

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a callback that is invoked synchronously (ie i know the order), just wait for callbcak to be invoked

```
.someCallback(function () {
    var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //closure
        var outer = function (ii) {
                alert(ii);
                var inner = function (ii) {
                    return abc[ii];
                }
                return inner(ii);
            } //closure
        return outer(i);
    }); //close loop
});
```

I am not using any framework, just raw .js; I cannot access code outside of this callback.

Problem is either lose inner variable when `return outer(i)`; cannot get past i=0 , or go through loop when just call `outer(i)`

how does this get done.

Comment: This will unavoidably results in three different function objects, with three different return values, which one do you want?

Comment: each time someCallBack gets invoked, i would like the next value: a, b, c

Comment: You'll have to use a global variable for that, then. It's not very recommended.

Comment: But then, shouldn't you be calling the callback function in the loop? That would simplify things

Comment: no, thats not an option... (unfortunately), ie thats the challenge... or is this not possible to have a dynamic loop or hold onto the index of the loop somehow

Comment: You can't have the loop inside the function! You're passing one and only one return value to the callback function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, not very clean, but works:

```
var i = 0
.someCallback(function() {
     var abc = ['a','b','c']
     //closure
     var outer = function(ii){
         alert(ii)  
         var inner = function(ii){
              return abc[ii];
            } 
     return inner(ii);
     }//closure
     i += 1
     return outer(i-1)
});//close function and call
```

Just hope this helps!

Comment: .someCallBack gets invoked by a key-press.  each time a key is pressed, i need the next value to be returned. First event return a, Next event return b, final event return c... is this possible ?

Comment: There you go, using globals.

Comment: ill have to check if i can put the var i =0 after the CallBack, but ill check that later, and if thats the case i think this works!

Comment: What happened to semi-decent code indentation?  Your solution is not very legible and is deceptive because of wrongly indented code.  Also, where'd the `for` loop go that was in the OP's question?  I don't see how your code executes 3 times like the OP indicated.

Comment: havent checked yet, but each time i click/call back invoked,  the var `i` gets incremented.. this is not asynch, i know it will be executed 3 times; thats why i marked it as the answer..